# Limits of sequence using epsilon

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I started to learn the limits of sequence and I really can't understand the logic of the definition. I really don't understand why we put the condition that exist an epsilon, why there exist an uppercase "N" greater that "n" and what is the role of that n. Thank you and have a nice day!

*Edit : Definition. We say that a sequence of numbers a1,a2,… converges to a number a if for each ε>0 you can find an n0∈N such that for every n≥n0 it holds:
|an−a|<ε.*

This is the definition which I can't understand.

Comment: Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Comment: Definition. We say that a sequence of numbers a1,a2,… converges to a number a if for each ε>0 you can find an n0∈N such that for every n≥n0 it holds:

|an−a|<ε.   I refer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Say it in ordinary language:

A sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ converges to a limit $\ell$ id $a_n$ can be made as close to $\ell$ as we please, provided we choose $a_n$ with a sufficiently high rank.

Numerically:
‘*as close to $\ell$ as we please*’ means that for any precision we choose ($\forall \varepsilon >0$, we shall have $|a_n-\ell|<\varepsilon$

‘*with a sufficiently high rank*’ means we  can find a rank $N$ from which this degree of precision will be attained, i.e.  $\;\exists N,\:\forall n\: (n>N\implies |a_n-\ell|<\varepsilon )$.

Is it clearer?

*Edit: an example*:

A standard limit is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n\bigr)=1$.  This means that we can make $\bigl|\bigl(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n\bigr)-1\bigr|$ as small as we please just choosing $n$ large enough.

Namely, we choose an $\varepsilon>0$, say $\varepsilon=10^{-6}$?. Let's evaluate the distance from $a_n$ to $1$, using the conjugate expression:
$$\bigl|a_n-1\bigr|=\bigl|\sqrt{n^2+2n}-(n+1\bigr)\bigr|=\left|\frac{n^2+2n-(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}+(n+1)}\right|=\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+2n}+(n+1)}.$$

Now $\sqrt{n^2+2n}>\sqrt{n^2}=n$, and $n+1>n$, so the denominator is larger than $2n$, and ultimately
$$[a_n-1|=\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+2n}+(n+1)}<\frac 1{2n}.$$
Therefore, to have $|a_n-1|<\varepsilon$, it suffices to choose $n$ such that
$$\frac 1{2n}<\varepsilon\iff  n> N=\frac1{2\varepsilon}= 500\,000\quad\text{for the given choice of }\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Can you give me a practical example ?

Comment: @AdrianȘtefan: I've added a (comparatively) detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary language, it means that for any open interval $I$ centered at $a$, it suffices to choose $n$ large enough to ensure that $a_n$ belongs to $I$.

The *open interval centered at* $a$ is $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$ and the $n$ *large enough* is the $n\ge n_0$ part.